# Baritone Clef using Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to implement the two Baritone Clefs. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\begin{document} 

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Treble}\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef11\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Soprano}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef12\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Mezzo}\zchar{9}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Soprano}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef13\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Alto}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef14\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Tenor}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef15\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Baritone}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef1\bass\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Bass}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setdoublebar
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use clef symbol substitution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\begin{document} 

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Treble}\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef11\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Soprano}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef12\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Mezzo}\zchar{9}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Soprano}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef13\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Alto}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef14\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Tenor}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    %%%%
    %%%% CHANGES BELOW
    \setclef15\Changeclefs%
    \setclef17\setclefsymbol1\smallaltoclef\Changeclefs%  NOTE1
    \setclef15\setclefsymbol1\empty\Changeclefs%  NOTE2
    \resetclefsymbols%  NOTE3
    %%%% END CHANGES
    %%%%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Baritone}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setclef1\bass\Changeclefs%
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\hspace*{-0.5cm}\A Bass}\qsk\wh{c}\en%\bar
    \setdoublebar
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

Which compiles to

[image]

Explanation / Notes:

1. In musixtex, Clef 0 is the G clef centered at the second line; Clefs 1, 2, 3, 4 are the C clef centered at the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th lines respectively; and Clefs 5, 6, and 7 are the F clef centered at the 3rd, 4th, and 5th lines. Clef 9 is the G clef on the first line. What you want to print is a C clef on the fifth line. So you can do clef-substitution:

   - First `\setclef17` to specify "F clef on fifth line"
   - Replace the clef symbol with `\setclefsymbol1\smallaltoclef` to print the C clef instead
   - Activate it with `\Changeclefs`
2. This however causes a problem as musictex will interpret all subsequent notes as specified relative to "F clef on fifth line"; to fix that, we reset the clef to the baritone clef with `\setclef15`. To suppress printing another clef symbol, we `\setclefsymbol1\empty` before `\Changeclefs`.
3. Finally, after all these shenanigans all the internal clef symbols are messed up, so we reset the clef symbols with `\resetclefsymbols` so that the next time you issue `\setclef<n><m>` you get the expected output.

Comment: In case we need to switch the order: 1st C Clef and 2nd F Clef, how to do that?

Comment: Just swap the relevant macros (see the explanation/notes above).

Comment: Done!!! Just to share the code: \setclef17\setclefsymbol1\smallaltoclef\Changeclefs%
    \setclef15\setclefsymbol1\smallbassclef\Changeclefs%

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution, including the right size of the key, the "alternate", and putting the name above the key, not above the note, because it is the name of the key, while the name of the note always remains "c" resp. "do". Besides, I presume that the names of the keys are (slightly) different in Spanish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\begin{document} 

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
    \NOTEs\cchar{13}{\bsk\A Treble}\wh{c}\en%
\NOTEs\altoclef\cchar{13}{\hbsk\A Soprano}\qsk\wh{e}\en%
    \NOTEs{\zcharnote g{\altoclef}}\qsk\cchar{14}{\A Mezzo}\cchar{10}{\A Soprano}\hsk\wh{g}\en%
    \NOTEs\zcharnote i{\altoclef}\qsk\cchar{14}{\A Alto}\hsk\wh{i}\en%
    \NOTEs\zcharnote k{\altoclef}\qsk\cchar{14}{\A Tenor}\hsk\wh{k}\en%
    \NOTEs\zcharnote M{\A alternate}\unbkt P{0.8}0\zcharnote m{\altoclef}\hsk\cchar{14}{\A Baritone}\zcharnote i{\bassclef}\qsk\hsk\wh{m}\en%
    \NOTEs\zcharnote k{\bassclef}\cchar{14}{\qsk\qsk\A Bass}\qsk\hsk\wh{o}\en%
    \setdoublebar
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

[image]